# how to only build libsmbclient-raw.so

Tags: samba, libsmbclient

I only need to build libsmbclient-raw.so in samba. I don't need any other tool or daemon in samba package. The samba version I am working on is samba-4.1.13. 
How can I only build libsmbclient-raw.so ?

Answer (score 2):

Run configure as normal. After that, run:

```
% make bin/shared/libsmbclient-raw.so.0
```

libsmbclient-raw.so should just be a symlink to libsmbclient-raw.so.0

Note that building libsmbclient-raw.so will pull in a lot of other code, so it will not be that much faster than building all of Samba.